# Need help understanding the specifics of external libraries

Tags: java

I'm a beginner Java developer seeking to know the specifics of how libraries work in Java.

Do external and internal libraries get linked statically or dynamically?

I ask because I've seen projects that have dependencies but build only one .jar file as output. This would suggest that the dependencies are loaded statically and yet I've read conflicting information that states that external libraries are loaded by the JVM using something called "ClassPath."

I compiled a small bare-bones program with maven shade plugin and got an original version and a shaded version. My understanding is that the shaded version is the one with all dependencies included within the file itself so it should be the only one that can run stand-alone. The original should need the dependencies in their expected locations in order for it to run and yet it runs just fine anywhere. I've been researching for a few hours now and haven't found anything on this matter. If I could get a clear explanation of how libraries are linked when projects are built and how the JVM handles these dependencies, I would be ecstatic.

Comment: You should probably start by asking what is a jar file... it's a zip file with a tiny bit of metadata. If your program has dependencies, then you either include them in your jar file (a "fatjar") or you must point to them on your CLASSPATH or your program will not work. Perhaps you only have transitive dependencies. Those are only needed at build time. Not runtime.

Comment: A JAR file is fundamentally just a ZIP file. The class files in a JAR file are found and loaded at run-time on an as-needed basis. As for your "bare-bones program", did you use any third-party libraries? Because if you only used code from the standard library then there is likely no difference between the shaded and non-shaded JAR file. The standard library is part of the JDK/JRE. Though note that even those class files are found and loaded at run-time on an as-needed basis.

Comment: And the "class-path" (also see "module-path" in Java 9+) is simply where the built-in class loaders will look when asked to load a class.

Comment: I think the concept of "static" and "dynamic" libraries in this context might not be appropriate. For example, you might make use of library (jar), which is required to be available at compile and run time. Now "technically" the third party library is "loaded" by the class loader dynamically, so it's not "included in" or "compiled into" the code, instead, if you either end up with multiple jars (which need a manifest in the core jar to determine which libraries need to be included) or a "fat" jar, which basically just throws all the classes into a single jar

Comment: You can also load Jars dynamically at runtime through the use of a custom classloader.  This is a great starting point for "plugins", but that's a whole other complicated discussion

Comment: And if you're using JNA or JNI to invoke native code, there is also `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which the JDK will use to load shared libraries dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

"Linking" isn't the term used by the java ecosystem. At any rate, everything in java links dynamically at all times.

> But, I have one jar and it runs fine!

Sure; it's still dynamically linked, it's just that everything that needs to be loaded is in that jar file.

> So how does it work?

A class is loaded by the ClassLoader and you can write your own. They can get it from absolutely anywhere, including 'generate it on the fly', 'download live', or 'get it from a database' if you want.

The standard classloader (because `java` itself needs to load your main classes, and it can't use some custom classloader because how do we load that classloader then? Chicken-and-egg problem) - is the one used by most apps without introducing their own.

The standard loader knows where java's own stuff is out of the box. On moden JVMs, its in all those jmod files in your java installation directly. Java just knows where these are, you don't need to put those dirs in your path, pass them to the java executable, or otherwise worry about them.

That leaves your own classes. The standard system launches with a 'class path', which consists of one of 3 things:

- A path that resolves to a directory on disk.
- A path that resolves to a jar file on disk.
- A path that ends in `*` literally (do not let bash replace that, so, single-quote it on linux), with a dir in front of it, e.g. `/com/foo/libs/*` - that will result in java expanding to including every jar file in that dir (but not recursively - not subdirs) on the classpath.

Java doesn't do anything with these and doesn't load a bunch of classes on bootup at all.

Instead, it tries to run your main class which it can't find in the bootclasspath, so we need to load a class (just that one class). This is done by rewriting the Fully Qualified Class Name, e.g. `com.foo.MyApp` to a path form (`/com/foo/MyApp.class`). Then, it looks in every classpath for that resource. For file paths, that's appended, for jars, that resource is looked for in the jar.

First hit wins and that is loaded. Running that class usually ends up requiring more classes to be loaded, which are resolved in the same way.

### ... so where is this classpath thing defined then?

Depends on how you load java. There are 4 ways to run `java.exe`:

- Pass a **java** file (source) file to it. There is no classpath, this works only if that java file can run on its own using only itself and bootclasspath.
- Just write out the name of a class, e.g. `java com.foo.Bar`. This means the environment variable `CLASSPATH` is used.
- Use the `-cp` param: `java -cp 'libs/*':myapp.jar com.foo.Bar` - well, you passed the classpath, that's what is used.
- Use the `-jar` param: `java -jar myapp.jar` - then **`-cp` and CLASSPATH are completely ignored!** - and instead the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` from inside the jar is opened, the key/value pair `Class-Path` from inside is read out. This classpath (which, if it doesn't exist, is taken as a blank string) gets the jar you pass prepended to it, and then that is the classpath. The `Class-Path` entry is space separated and relative **to the dir the jar you are running is in**, so it just doesn't matter in which working dir you are when you `java -jar` it.

### So how should I deploy my jars?

The java ecosystem tends to shade. They are all wrong. Shading is rarely correct. It's slow and requires transfering far more data than is needed.

Instead, add `Class-Path` (all build tools can do it). For example, have:

```
/myapp/myapp.jar
/myapp/libs/lib1.jar
/myapp/libs/lib2.jar
```

And have `Class-Path: libs/lib1.jar libs/lib2.jar` in the manifest (again a thing all build systems can do for you). Then, that jar will 'just work'. Even if you are in `/home/foo` and run `java -jar /myapp/myapp.jar`. Replace the `lib` jars only you have a new version to deploy, no need to replace them otherwise.

shading is nice when deploying to systems you don't control, except, that doesn't work either: You can't/should not ask end users to install java, **you** have to do that, with an installer, for example jlink + jpackage. The JRE has been mostly dead as a concept for a decade.

Comment: Small correction, if you use `java com.foo.Bar` it looks in the current working directory and on the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: "_On moden JVMs, its in all those jmod files in your java installation directly_" -- I don't believe that's correct. JMOD files cannot be used at run-time, only link-time (`jlink`) and compile-time. There is a `lib/modules` file (at least on Windows) as part of the JDK/JRE, and if I'm not mistaken, that's the "run-time image" (i.e., where all "jlinked" modules are, and thus where the "built-in" classes are loaded from).